# Angular 16: unable to override "baseUrl" in tsconfig.app.json

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths, tsconfig.json

I have created a new workspace using Angular CLI and added 2 projects to it, one lib and one application. Running the app `"my-app"` with `"ng serve"` works fine.

After copying `.ts` files over to the new "my-app" project I get compiler errors, and relative paths are not recognized:

```
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
```

this only works if I change it to:

```
import { environment } from 'projects/my-app/src/environments/environment';
```

My project structure:

```
+ node_modules
+ projects
| + my-app
| | + src
| | | + app
| | | | - app.module.ts (etc.)
| | | + environments
| | | | - environment.ts
| | - tsconfig.app.json
- tsconfig.json
- package.json
```

So far I've tried to override `"baseUrl"` of `tsconfig.app.json` with many values, but none of them worked:

```
"projects/my-app/src"
"src",
"./src"
```

(using VS Code I restarted TS server many times: `Ctrl + P > "Typescript: restart TS Server`" with no effect; seems like TS compiler does not read `tsconfig.app.json` at all)

Setting `"baseUrl"` in the workspace's `tsconfig.json` file works:

workspace tsconfig.json:

```
...
"baseUrl": "./projects/my-app/src",
...
```

but since I'm going to add other projects to the workspace later, I prefer not to solve it this way.

I know about adding shortcuts to `tsconfig.json` > `"paths"`, but I'd have to change hundreds, maybe thousands of `.ts` file `import` statements:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["........"],
      "@pages/*": ["...../pages/*"],
      "@components/*": ["...../components/*"],
      "@state/*": ["...../state/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I tell my Angular project's TS compiler that I've overridden `baseUrl` in `tsconfig.app.json` ?

Comment: Angular is a nightmare for libs development. The real  scenario is to have the app and the lib in different git repositories. Is an option to you the usage of a local npm repository?

Comment: @JRichardsz of course, I could split the workspace into different git repos, but then what's the point of having Angular workspaces? TBH I'd expect Angular CLI to take care of this paths problem when creating the project, or at least give a warning or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for this (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping and https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths):

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths" : {
            "*" : ["*", "projects/app1/src/*", "projects/app2/src/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

> Please notice that paths are resolved relative to baseUrl. When setting baseUrl to a value other than ".", i.e. the directory of tsconfig.json, the mappings must be changed accordingly.

This tells the compiler for any module import that matches the pattern "*" (i.e. all values), to look in two locations:

1. `*`: meaning the same name unchanged, so map

`<moduleName> => <baseUrl>/<moduleName>`

2. `projects/app1/src/*` meaning the module name with an appended prefix, so map `<moduleName> => <baseUrl>/projects/app1/src/<moduleName>`

Keep `src` in your paths depends only on your needs, just change them as you wish.

Comment: I removed "baseUrl" from tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.json's "paths" look like this now:

"paths": {
      "my-lib": [ "dist/my-lib" ],
      "*": [ "*", "projects/my-app/src/*" ]
}

and it worked. Thanks a lot!!